# I'm playing music that trigger in the background mode - but it stops after a sec, why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm playing sound that trigger in the background but it sound less then a sec.
i have tried wav and m4a files. but I'm getting crazy finding an answer to the problem.
its not even finished one loop.. do you know why its happened ? can someone please help me?

**this is the playing code:**

```
NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[userProp valueForKey:@"romba"] ofType:@"m4a"];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath] error:NULL]; 
audioPlayer.delegate=self;
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer play];
```

i have tried to call this delegate functions to check the problem but nothing I'm my console

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    NSLog(@"finish playing");
}

-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"stops - decoder error");
    NSLog(@"error: %@",[error description]);
}
-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player{
    NSLog(@"stops - decoder error");
}
```

this is the way I'm adding the AVAudoioPlayer -

```
-(void)syncAlarmProperties{
    NSUserDefaults *userProp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[userProp valueForKey:@"alertProp"] ofType:@"wav"];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath] error:NULL]; 

    audioPlayer.delegate=self;
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops=-1;

}
```

this is playing function:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
{
[audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Is the `-audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:` delegate method being reached?

Comment: Does your delegate get any messages of relevance?

Comment: i just update the question with answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Automatic Reference Counting, then `audioPlayer` is probably being sent a `-release` message immediately following the `-play` message.

The solution in this case is to add your instance of `AVAudioPlayer` as a `@property` on your class to ensure that the player will not be released out from under you.

Comment: i really believe you on the way to help me.. but i did add @property to my class - but it still same problem.

Comment: this class is ok ?

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

Comment: Yes. Then configure your `AVAudioPlayer` in `-init`. Now all you have to do to play the file is send `[self.audioPlayer play];`.

Comment: configure in `-init` ?! i don't have init function in my m file.. and it still not working..

Comment: By `-init`, I mean your designated initializer. Are you loading from a nib? Use `-initWithCoder:`.

Comment: its loaded automatically - I'm using     `audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath]error:NULL];`

Comment: I just understand you and it's still not working good, maybe you have another options?

Comment: Edit your question to show the methods where you create it and play it.

Comment: i changed the way its built in my project. i made it load with nib. but still same problem... I'm getting crazy...